# Set visibility of dropbox files/folders as public or private using api php

Tags: dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I am trying to implement dropbox apis using php in my website for sharing. Using shares() I am able to get share link for a folder/file but visibility is always "PUBLIC". Is there any method/api to set the visibility? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, the Dropbox API doesn't currently expose a way to set the visibility of shared links. We're tracking this as a feature request though.